# Перенаправлять на другой сайт, если определенный class

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-web

Скачал библиотеку devise.js, она, в зависимости от устройства с которого заходят на сайт, присваивает тегу `html` определенный `class`.(прим. desktop, phone и тд.). Так вот, помогите с JS скриптом, который получает значение этого класса в теге и если он phone, то перенаправляет на мобильную версию сайта. В JS не силен. Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функциями `device.js` вместо постройки костылей:

```
<script src="device.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

   if( device.mobile() ) {
       window.location = "mobile.site"
   }

</script>
```